# fatal exception : asynctask #1 doInBackground when i using Soap

Tags: android

when i run my code i get this Error and i don't know why !!!
i think my Error in doinbackground method but i don't know the reason 
i have class SoapConnection this make my Connection with Web Service and when i run my application and write correct Username and password the new Activity Open normally but when write incorrect username or password i show this Error (fatal exception : asynctask #1 doInBackground)

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends Activity {

TextView lblRenewal, lblForgot;
private static EditText txtUser , txtPass;  
Button btnLogin, btnCancel;
ProgressDialog pDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    txtUser =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    txtPass =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);

    lblRenewal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblRenewal);
    lblRenewal.setClickable(true);
    lblRenewal.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    String text = "<a href='http://www.Google.com/' > google </a>";
    lblRenewal.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

    lblForgot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblForgot);
    lblForgot.setPaintFlags(lblForgot.getPaintFlags()
            | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
    lblForgot.setClickable(true);

    lblForgot.setOnClickListener(lblForget_Click);

    btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(btnCancel_Click);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(btnLogin_Click);

}

private OnClickListener lblForget_Click = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent PasswordRecovery = new Intent(
                "com.examples.myapp.FORGOTPASSWORD");
        startActivity(PasswordRecovery);
    }
};


private OnClickListener btnCancel_Click = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
};

private OnClickListener btnLogin_Click = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        try{
        AsyncTask<String, Object , Object> LoginTask = new AsyncTask<String, Object, Object>(){


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if(pDialog.isShowing())
                    {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    }

            }


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                params.put("User", txtUser.getText());
                params.put("Pass", txtPass.getText());
                SoapConnection SC = new SoapConnection("UserExists", "http://10.0.2.2:38176/Android/BCWS.asmx?WSDL");
                SC.params = params;
                String Result =SC.StartConnection(); 
                if(Result.equals(txtUser.getText().toString())){
                        Intent m = new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(m);
                }else{
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, Result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return Result;
            }
        };

        LoginTask.execute();
        }catch( Exception e ){
        txtUser.setText("Error");
        }

    }
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}


enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `doInBackground` you are updating ui which is not possible. You need to update ui on the ui thread. `doInBackground` is invoked on the background thread,

In `onPostExecute` display `Toast` and `startActivity`.

Comment: @Michael return result in doInbackground. The result is a param to onPostExecute. Depending on the result do whatever is required

Comment: @Michael you are welcome. You can also check the source http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/os/AsyncTask.java#AsyncTask.execute%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29 and the docs for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            params.put("User", txtUser.getText());
            params.put("Pass", txtPass.getText());
            SoapConnection SC = new SoapConnection("UserExists",     "http://10.0.2.2:38176/Android/BCWS.asmx?WSDL");
            SC.params = params;
            String Result =SC.StartConnection(); 
            if(Result.equals(txtUser.getText().toString())){
                    Intent m = new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(m);
            }else{
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, Result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//this is your error, 
            }
            return Result;
```

You cannot update UI within doInBackground you Should call Toast in onPostExecute Method, Just Do the following.

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(pDialog.isShowing())
                {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            if(Result.equals(txtUser.getText().toString())){
                    Intent m = new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(m);
            }else{
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, Result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//this is your error, 
            } 

        }
```

Comment: when i do it the program give me Error under Result Word

Answer (score 0):

This

```
Toast.makeText(Login.this, Result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

can not run in doInBackground. Either move it to onPostExecute or wrap with runOnUiThread like this:

```
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            params.put("User", txtUser.getText());
            params.put("Pass", txtPass.getText());
            SoapConnection SC = new SoapConnection("UserExists", "http://10.0.2.2:38176/Android/BCWS.asmx?WSDL");
            SC.params = params;
            String Result =SC.StartConnection(); 
            if(Result.equals(txtUser.getText().toString())){
                    Intent m = new Intent(Login.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(m);
            }else{
              Login.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                  public void run() {
                   Toast.makeText(Login.this, Result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              }
           }
            return Result;
        }
     });
```